# How to deploy branch specific code using GIT?

Tags: git-ftp

I am using separate servers for dev, test and production environments. I have git installed on my local machine and have separate branches for each environment. How can I deploy the code from each branch to its respective server using GIT?

FYI: GIT is not installed on server.

Thanks in advance.

Simrat

Answer (score -2):

You should have git installed on server,
use the following command  to  push you code to your remote repository

```
git push remote_repository_url  branch_name
```

use the following commands to fetch or deploy the code from remote repository to your corresponding machine .

```
 git  pull  remote_repository_url    branch_name 

                  or 

 git  fetch  remote_repository_url   branch_name
```

Use  fetch command  to avoid the merging

Even you can use  **git clone**  command  to clone the  specific  branch from your remote_repository(assembla)  to  your corresponding server >

```
git  clone  --branch  branch_name   remote_repository_url
```

Comment: I have remote repository on assembla and I am pushing all the code to it. I have development, test and production environments setup on different servers. I am using one repository with different branches for each environment. Is there any way to deploy branch specific code to its respective server?

Comment: You can use either "fetch" or "pull" command to retrieve the branch specific code from the remote server to the corresponding machine.

to pull data:  "git pull  remote_repository_url       branch_name"

Comment: Yes I push all my code to assembla. I think you are not getting my question. I am using assembla as remote repository but have different servers for dev, test and prod environments where I need to push/deploy my code from different branches of same repository.

Comment: Yes I understood , you can directly fetch the core to corresponding server or machine(dev,test,production) from the assembla  by using either "fetch"  command  or  "pull"  command in the because you have all the three branch codes on  remote_server(assembla) .
So  use  "git  pull  remote_repoame   branch_name " or  "git fetch  remote_reponame  branch_name  on corresponding  server" >

Comment: I have shell access to the dev server but my production environment is on a shared server and I can't install git on it. I have the login credentials which I use to deploy code through FTP. Is there any way to deploy the code using git on local machine without having git installed on the server?

Comment: you have one way , clone it to your machine and then transfer it to the corresponding machine(lets say your production machine )